# Python script being killed

Tags: python, python-2.7, kill

I have a program that runs for a while and outputs "Killed". I can't imagine that it's a memory thing because the file it's loading is under a gig. I've been trying to Google what other things can cause a python script to be killed but all I can find are articles about people being eaten by snakes... Here is my code:

```
import neo
from neo.io import BlackrockIO

dir = '/PHShome/gcw8/Ephys_Test/MG79_d4_Sat.ns3'
reader = BlackrockIO(filename=dir)
blks = reader.read(lazy=False, cascade=True)

for blk in blks:
    for seg in blk.segments:
            print 'Sampling Rate = %s' %seg.analogsignals[0].sampling_rate
    print 'Number of Channels = %d' %len(blk.recordingchannelgroups[0].recordingchannels)
```

A little background. The file I'm working on is an electrophysioloy data file that consists of

1.) a header containing metadata (small)

2.) data (large)

the `lazy` option of `reader.read()` loads only the header when set to `True` and loads the entire file (including the data) when set to `False`. The code is not killed when `lazy = True` but does crash when `lazy = False`. While `lazy = False` causes much, much more of the file to be read,

`[gcw8@database_dev Ephys_Test]$ du -h ./MG79_d4_Sat.ns3 
 719M   ./MG79_d4_Sat.ns3`

So I have trouble beleiving that it is a memory issue. Can anyone think of another reason this is being killed or a work around? I'm running Python 2.7 on CentOS.

Comment: That [BlackrockIO library](https://github.com/NeuralEnsemble/python-neo/blob/master/neo/io/blackrockio.py) appears to parse the data and do all sorts of things with it. It could be that you actually ARE running out of memory. You could try monitoring memory usage using e.g. `htop`.

Comment: The OOM killer logs to *somewhere* under `/var/log`, but cursory Googling is giving me conflicting results.  You might be able to check those logs directly.

Comment: @ThomWiggers you were right, it was a memory issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That [BlackrockIO library](https://github.com/NeuralEnsemble/python-neo/blob/master/neo/io/blackrockio.py) appears to parse the data and do all sorts of things with it. It could be that you actually ARE running out of memory. You could try monitoring memory usage using e.g. htop.